# Switching a YouTube account to a different email address

Tags: youtube, google-account

I have a Google+ business page and Gmail address. I have a YouTube account that has a lot of data that somehow got linked to a different email address and Google+ page (with no info). I have been trying for days to switch the email address so that the YouTube info will be with my Google+ page and Gmail address and cannot get the data there since I can't figure out how to get the email changed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you sign out of YouTube you should be able to re-sign to the same account using whatever email you want to link to your account, Just figured this out myself. Had a friend check their email and suddenly my YouTube was on their email.

Comment: Adding a link or screenshot would be more helpful.